# Using $ionicLoading inside a factory

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to use `$ionicLoading` inside a factory. (I thought it's a good idea to have the code in one place without repeating it in each controller)

```
angular.module('<my app>.message', ['ionic'])                                                                                                                                  
   .factory('Message', [function($scope, $ionicLoading){                                                                                                                          

     var messageFactory = {};                                                                                                                                                     

    messageFactory.successMessage = function(message){                                                                                                                           
       $ionicLoading.show({ templateUrl: 'templates/messages/success.html',                                                                                                       
                            noBackdrop: true, duration: 1000 });                                                                                                                  
     }                                                                                                                                                                            
     return messageFactory;                                                                                                                                                       
   }]);
```

But the problem is I'm getting this error `Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`, Since the same code works fine in the controller, I'm wondering if this meant to be working inside a controller. If so , my question is how can I avoid using the same code for message boxes inside a project.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax problem ([see this for details](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)).

You are not injecting correctly. Your code should be like:

`.factory('Message', ['$scope', '$ionicLoading', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {`

I prefer to annotate my code automatically in build step. See [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) for details

This is my factory for "toasting" messages on browser or device:
When running in Cordova, show the native toast. Outside of Cordova, show an Ionic popup ($ionicLoading) for the same period of time.
Uses the API for the Toast plugin - message, duration, position.
Differences are that: Ionic popup ignores position, and doesn't allow doing anything while it shows.

(requires [Toast Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/toast/))

```
.factory('Toast', function($ionicLoading, $cordovaToast) {
    return {
        show: function (message, duration, position) {
            message = message || "No message given...";
            duration = duration || 'short';
            position = position || 'top';

            if (!!window.cordova) { // Use the Cordova Toast plugin
                $cordovaToast.show(message, duration, position);
            }
            else {
                duration = 2000;
                $ionicLoading.show( { template: message, duration: duration } );

            }
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: What is the OP's syntax problem?